Excel Function not working after a certain number
So I have this formula which does an hlookup and it works fine till around 68 so it gets the .99 identifier and adds it to the run number which is 68 in this case and it returns a N/A however the part that is stumping me is that it works perfectly fine from 1-60 (1.99,2.99,etc.) but as soon as it gets to 68.99 (where data does exsist and is formatted correctly) it breaks. Same formula for all lookups between 1-60.
    =IF(HLOOKUP($B$21+$CA$8,Input_Data!$A$2:$BIN$2502,$BZ10,FALSE)<>0,
HLOOKUP($B$21+$CA$8,Input_Data!$A$2:$BIN$2502,$BZ10,FALSE), #N/A)

This is not a duplicate question im wondering how to fix it because I believe it is because im matching floating point numbers.

Matching on floating-point numbers is likely to run into this sort of issue.

Actually this is not a duplicate question because I fixed it this is a question for whether the formula is breaking or is it excel hardware limits.

@MayukhBhattacharya why did you reopen this? This does seem like a self-duplicate indeed.

Please create a [reprex] including sample data, the expected result, and the current result.

Actually i read the question, found its different and could not go through all,  is it duplicate? Ok OP confirms not duplicate.

Have you considered using ROUND?

=HLOOKUP(68.99,Input_Data!$A$2:$BIN$2502,5,FALSE)

hmm also I havent how would I incoporate that into it

also here =HLOOKUP(68.99,Input_Data!$A$2:$BIN$2502,5,FALSE) expected: .433, I get: N/A same code with 60.99 =HLOOKUP(60.99,Input_Data!$A$2:$BIN$2502,5,FALSE) expected/what I get: .433,  I am starting to lean more towards excel capabilities because I am unsure why it would just stop after a certain number, This all from the same sheet which each row and column is formatted the exact same way. All I have to make it work is move it the data to the "60" identifier but since there is bulk uploads which exceed 60 I need it to work indefinitely

Please post some sample data using Markdown_Table_Generator so that one can visualize and help you out with a formula. Also have you tried to follow the suggestions as commented yet?
